# Let $A$ be such a set that its power set $P(A)$ is a chain with inclusion as the partial ordering. What can be said about $P(A)$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I don't have a solution manual to this specific exercise and they don't give a hint what kind of answer they are looking for. The problem is picked from Kaplansky "*Set Theory and Metric Spaces*".

Does anyone here have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $A$ has at most one element.

Comment: Okey, to make things clear: $P(A)=\left \{ \varnothing  , \left \{ x_i \right \},\left \{ x_i,x_j \right \},...,A \right \}$. Therefore $\left(P(A), \subseteq \right)$ is a chain where: $\varnothing \subseteq  \left\{ x_i \right \} \cdots A$. Since $ \left\{ x_i \right \} \subseteq \left\{ x_j \right \}$ is not true, $\left\{ x_i \right \}=A$ and therefore $A$ contains, as a maximum, one element. @Stefan Mesken

Comment: @CarlSchmidt That's the right idea but I would phrase is slightly differently: If $x,y \in A$ are distinct, then $\{x\}, \{y\} \in \mathcal P(A)$ but $\{x \} \not \subseteq \{y\}$ and $\{y \} \not \subseteq \{x \}$. Hence $A$ can contain at most one element. On the other hand, if $A$ contains at most one element, it's easy to check that $\mathcal P (A)$ is a chain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, got it!

Comment: @CarlSchmidt You're welcome!

Comment: Just to clarify, $A=\left \{x, x, x, x, x, x, x, ... \right \}$ right? @StefanMesken

Comment: @CarlSchmidt I'm not sure what you're asking. $\{x,x,x, \ldots \} = \{ x \}$ -- we don't count the multiplicity in sets.

Comment: Okey! now I got it! I didn't know that...